# Wordpress get multiple posts by id

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get multiple posts in wordpress by ID.

```
get_posts('p=34,36');
```

I assumed that that might work, but it only gives the first post.

I tried then to use an array:

```
$args = array( 'p' => array(34,36));
```

That delivered no results.

`get_posts('p=34+36');` NO and `get_posts('p=34&p=36');` Last one only

Any ideas?

Comment: You were quite persistent before asking :). Kudos for that. Some tries that are missing: "p=34-36", "p=34 to 36", "where p = 34 or p = 36", "please give me posts 34 and 36", "please wordpress, please? give me posts 34 and 36" :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'post__in' => array(34,36) );
```

Be sure to check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query as well, the section **Interacting with WP_Query** will be very valuable to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$args = array( 
           'post_type' => 'page', // must
           'post__in' => array(34,36) 
        );
$posts = get_posts($args);
print_r($posts);
```

this may help you.